# CSS text align justify big spaces

Tags: css, justify

To format paragraphs I use `text-align:justify`, but I have one problem that there are big spaces between words, for IE the solution is to use `text-justify: distribute;`, but Chrome doesn't support this, my question is what should I use for Chrome and Firefox

Example of big spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/L5drN/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using hyphenation (manual, CSS, server-side, or client-side JavaScript), see e.g. answers to [Can I use CSS to justify text with hyphenating words at the end of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511014/can-i-use-css-to-justify-text-with-hyphenating-words-at-the-end-of-a-line) 
Hyphenation tends to help a lot when there are long words in the text.

You can still keep `text-justify: distribute`, as it can improve the result on supporting browsers, and it can be expected to gain support, as it in the CSS standardization track (in [CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/) WD).

Comment: Thank's, but I steel have problem width Chrome

Comment: Chrome does not do hyphenation yet, so for Chrome, you are limited to the other options. Hyphenator.js seems hyphenate Lithuanian OK; demo: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/js/hyphlt.html8

Answer (score 48):

Give negative values as you prefer for word-spacing..

ex:

```
text-align:justify;
word-spacing:-2px;
```

Works for me and Hope this helps :)

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it works partially, it does not work for all lines, some lines maintain large spaces.

Answer (score 25):

Use:

> word-break: break-all;

And Ok!

Comment: Using this with `text-align: justify;` worked for me

Comment: In my case (there is a text in a paragraph) this will break the words. Not so good for the continous reading.

Comment: Partially worked for me, characters that don't fit will go on a new line, alone

Answer (score 7):

I got something satisfying by combining both methods:

- enable hyphens (using two variants for compatibility)
- negative word spacing (no more than -0.05em otherwise text get condensed)

```css
div.justify {
    text-align: justify;
    hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    word-spacing: -0.05em;
}

div.font {
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="justify font">In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. It is also used to temporarily replace text in a process called greeking, which allows designers to consider the form of a webpage or publication, without the meaning of the text influencing the design.</div>
```

Comment: Tnx, only hyphens: auto; helped to my justified texts to not have extreme gaps. Other solutions did not work. Tnx.

Answer (score 6):

```
text-align: justify;
text-justify: distribute;
text-align-last: left;
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 4):

```
hyphens: auto;
text-align: justify;
word-spacing: -0.5px;
```

Add these three lines to your text field css rule and see, while it may not give you perfect result, it will surley come close to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to format the paragraphs? Do you mean the width, height, letter spacing or word spacing?

Have you tried using the  *text-align* CSS tag?

```
text-align:center
```

Or the *word-spacing* CSS tag?

```
word-spacing:10px
```

Comment: He's using text-align:justify

Comment: I'm about that space between words are not same 1 is biggest that 2

Comment: @Lopezito Perhaps try using the CSS word spacing property then. It defines the spaces between words. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: Those aren't "CSS tags"! They're CSS Properties

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how anyone didn't think of this but this worked for me.

```css
text-align: start;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have an alternate solution to get rid of the big spacing between word
first you should know one thing that `text-align:justify` is used only when you are rendering your text component on wider screen so in my case I was using it on card custom component so I simply increase the width of my card component and this helps me hope it will help you to.

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Card.module.css'

const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.card}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
} ;


export default Card;
```

**Card.module.css**

```
.card {
          height: 30rem;
          width: 25rem;
          margin: 0 20px 10rem;
          text-align: justify;
         
    

}
```

**Calling card component in HOC**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import projectStyles from "./project.module.css";
import Card from "../UX/Card";
import axios from "axios";

const Project = () => {
  const [loadedProjects, setLoadedUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await axios("api/projects");

        setLoadedUsers(responseData.data.projects);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const displayHandler = (
    <div className={projectStyles.projectHolder}>
      {loadedProjects.map((project,index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index}>
            <img src={project.image} alt="project" height={225} width={345}  style={{marginBottom:"20px"}}/>
            <p style={{fontSize:'25px' , fontWeight:'bold'}}>{project.title}</p>
            <p className={projectStyles.body}>{project.info}</p>
            <h4>Technologies Used</h4>
            <ul key={project.image}>
              {project.technology.map((tech) => {
                return <li key={tech}>{tech}</li>;
              })}
            </ul>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

  return <div>{loadedProjects ? displayHandler : 'Fetching Projects...'}</div>;
};

export default Project;
```