# How to Remove unwanted white space between texts in a justified paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

i tried white-space, word-wrap and break-word properties in css but, i am not able to remove the white space between words . please give me any other solution how to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about multiple spaces between words where you only need one space?

Comment: This answer has already a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118540/css-text-align-justify-big-spaces

Comment: I am getting more unwanted spaces between words after aligning them to text-align: justify . i tried some css properties but i am not able to reduce the space between words

Comment: i tried to give word spacing in negative . but it is not properly working .

Answer (score -1):

Try to use negative value in `word-spacing` rule :

```
text-align:justify;
word-spacing:-2px;
```

Solution form @Laksh : [CSS text align justify big spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118540/css-text-align-justify-big-spaces)

Comment: while giving  'word-spacing:-2px;' all words not getting same space . some words getting more space between them

Comment: yeah this is bad