# Can't properly use text-align:justify

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a text that I want to have the property (text-align:justify;)

However, when I use this property on responsive it makes huge gaps in between the words. Anyone know how can I solve this without having to give every single text in the website different properties at different @medias?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15118540/4985572

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your textarea or p tag

```
style = "word-wrap: break-word";
```